# Let $V = W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$. Show that $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2} = \varnothing$ and $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cup\mathcal{B}_{2}$ is a basis for $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, direct-sum

(a) Let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $V = W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$. If $\mathcal{B}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{2}$ are basis for $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$, respectively, show that $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2} = \varnothing$ and $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cup\mathcal{B}_{2}$ is a basis for $V$.

(b) Conversely, let $\mathcal{B}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{2}$ be disjoint basis for $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$, respectively, of a vector space $V$. Prove that if $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cup\mathcal{B}_{2}$ is a basis for $V$, then $V = W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) Since $V = W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$, given $v\in V$, it can be (uniquely) written as $v = w_{1} + w_{2}$, where $w_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $w_{2}\in W_{2}$.

If we denote a basis of $W_{1}$ by $\mathcal{B}_{1} = \{w_{11},w_{12},\ldots,w_{1m}\}$ and a basis of $W_{2}$ by $\mathcal{B}_{2} = \{w_{21},w_{22},\ldots,w_{2n}\}$, we conclude that $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cup\mathcal{B}_{2}$ spans $V$. Since $\dim V = \dim W_{1} + \dim W_{2}$, it results that $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cup\mathcal{B}_{2}$ is a basis for $V$.

In order to support such claims, we have made use of the following proposition:

> Given a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ as well as two subspaces $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ of it, one has that
>   \begin{align*}
> \dim(W_{1}) + \dim(W_{2}) = \dim(W_{1} + W_{2}) + \dim(W_{1}\cap W_{2})
> \end{align*}

as well as

> If the set of vectors $\mathcal{B}\subset V$ spans $V$ and $|\mathcal{B}| = \dim V$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V$, where $V$ a finite dimensional vector space.

and we are done with the second part of the problem. Let us now prove that $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2} = \varnothing$.

Indeed, if it was not the case, we should have a vector $v\in\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2}$ which is not the null vector.

Since $\text{span}\{v\}\subseteq\text{span}(\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2})\subseteq\text{span}(\mathcal{B}_{1}) = W_{1}$ and $\text{span}\{v\}\subseteq\text{span}(\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2})\subseteq\text{span}(\mathcal{B}_{2}) = W_{2}$, we conclude that $v\in W_{1}\cap W_{2}$, which is impossible because $W_{1}\cap W_{2} = \{0\}$. Thus $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2} = \varnothing$.

(b) Once again, we shall assume that $\dim V = k$, $\dim W_{1} = m$ and $\dim W_{2} = n$.

Since $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cap\mathcal{B}_{2} = \varnothing$ and $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cup\mathcal{B}_{2}$ is a basis for $V$, any vector $v\in V$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
v = a_{1}w_{11} + a_{2}w_{12} + \ldots + a_{m}w_{1m} + b_{1}w_{21} + b_{2}w_{22} + \ldots + b_{n}w_{2n} = w_{1} + w_{2}
\end{align*}
where $w_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $w_{2}\in W_{2}$. Consequently, $V = W_{1} + W_{2}$.

Besides, $W_{1}\cap W_{2} = \{0\}$. Otherwise, we would have a contradiction.

Precisely speaking, let us assume there exists $v\neq 0$ and $v\in W_{1}\cap W_{2}$. Thus $v\in W_{1}$ and $v\in W_{2}$. Therefore we should have
\begin{align*}
v & = c_{1}w_{11} + c_{2}w_{12} + \ldots + c_{m}a_{1m} = d_{1}w_{21} + d_{2}w_{22} + \ldots + d_{n}w_{2n}\\\\
& \Rightarrow c_{1}w_{11} + c_{2}w_{12} + \ldots + c_{m}a_{1m} - d_{1}w_{21} - d_{2}w_{22} - \ldots - d_{n}w_{2n} = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow c_{1} = c_{2} = \ldots = c_{m} = d_{1} = d_{2} = \ldots = d_{n} = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow v = 0
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction. This is because the elements of $\mathcal{B}_{1}\cup\mathcal{B}_{2}$ are LI, and we are done.

Comment: Seems fine, but a word of advice: you should try to prove these statements without any appeal to dimensionality. Part of the beauty of axiomatic linear algebra is that it lets you prove things about vector spaces even when they are infinite dimensional, so that you can't appeal e.g. to matrices. Your statements should be true in infinite dimensional vector spaces as well, but your proof doesn't make this clear.

Comment: You don't need to use spans to prove $\mathcal B_1 \cap \mathcal B_2 = \varnothing$. if $v \in \mathcal B_1 \cap \mathcal B_2$, then $v \in \mathcal B_1 \subset W_1$ and $v \in \mathcal B_2 \subset W_2$, so $v \in W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$, but since the $\mathcal B_i$ are bases, they do not contain $0$, so $v \ne 0$. Also, I cannot agree more with Ethan Dlugie - while your logic here is okay, you would be wise to try to prove this without discussing dimensions. It will deepen your understanding of what is going on, which will be very helpful to you in the near future.

Comment: I would like to thanks both of you, EthanDlugie and PaulSinclair, for the constructive comments. I will take it into account from now on.